# Error while using guard with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am following the "Intro to rails Screencast - the tutorial I wish I had" from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had/?search_index=2

Based on that I added the following gems to my file -

```
group :test, :development do 
  gem 'turn'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'libnotify'
end
```

I than ran the following commands -

```
rails g rspec:install
guard init rspec
guard
```

I get the following error on running guard. I should be instead seeing the failed tests. I have already generated an integration test -

> Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are
>   running `guard` outside of Bundler. If this is your intent, feel free
>   to ignore this message. Otherwise, consider using `bundle exec guard`
>   to ensure your dependencies are loaded correctly. (You can run `guard`
>   with --no-bundler-warning to get rid of this message.)
>
> Guard uses Libnotify to send notifications. Guard is now watching at
>   '/home/murtaza/workspace/rails/tasks' Guard::RSpec is running, with
>   RSpec 2! Running all specs gem install minitest
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:9:in
>   `<class:TestCase>': uninitialized constant
>   Test::Unit::TestCase::Assertions (NameError)  from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in`
>   '   from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:4:in
>   `<module:Test>'   from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:3:in`
>   '    from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:5:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:4:in`
>   '    from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:2:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/rails.rb:10:in`
>   '    from
>   /home/murtaza/workspace/rails/tasks/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from
>   /home/murtaza/workspace/rails/tasks/spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:1:in`
>   require'     from
>   /home/murtaza/workspace/rails/tasks/spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`load'  from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'  from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`map'   from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'   from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in`run'     from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in
>   `run'     from
>   /home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in`
>   block in autorun'
>   >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the 'turn' gem. Removing it does the trick.

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/484

Answer (score 1):

Try running `bundle exec guard` as your final command instead of running `guard`.

The `bundle exec` portion of the command tells guard to run within the gems that were loaded via `Bundler`.  Bundler is a tool that allows your local folder to have it's own gem environment.

That's what the error message indicates:

> Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are running guard outside of Bundler. If this is your intent, feel free to ignore this message. Otherwise, consider using bundle exec guard to ensure your dependencies are loaded correctly. (You can run guard with --no-bundler-warning to get rid of this message.)